# Wildcard for hitTestObject ActionScript3 show Instance Name

Tags: string, actionscript-3, testing, movieclip, hit

I have movieClips namely rec1, rec2, rec3, rec4...

Then, I would addChild another movieclip(circle_mc) to those rec MovieClips.

I want to use the hitTestObject... Something like this:

```
circle_mc.hitTestObject(this["rec" + numStringTarget])
```

If I specify number on the numStringTarget variable, I can only attach to one of the "rec" movieclips. What I want is the capability of circle_mc to be added on any "rec" movieclips. Is there any way to use wildcard? Or any way to solve it?

I want the code to become like this:

```
circle_mc.hitTestObject(contains String "rec") then addChild..
```

I hope someone can solve it or just give me some helpful links to read about. Thanks in advance.

I do not want to set all these statements this way:

```
circle_mc.hitTestObject(rec1);
circle_mc.hitTestObject(rec2);
circle_mc.hitTestObject(rec3);
circle_mc.hitTestObject(rec4);
```

what if I have a hundreds or thousands... I want to test if the movieclip, as long as it has word "rec" on its instance name, it will be tested.

Or it could be in another situation. My circle_mc is draggable. Then when it hit another movieclip on stage, is there any way to show up the instance name hit by the circle_mc?

Comment: I don't get your question fully. When you want rec1, rec2 etc. i.e. what is the condition to add a particular rec?

Comment: Sir, I would like to add circle_mc to the rec movieclips... its either rec1, rec2, rec3, or any available rec movieclip on the stage. I can specify circle_mc.hitTestObject(rec1) to detect if it is hit. But circle_mc on that statement code specifically good only for rec1. What I want is that I can test if circle_mc has hit any of the rec movieclips, rec1, rec2 etc. If yes, then it will be added to it after detection.

Comment: Can't you loop through for all recs, i.e. loop numStringTarget from 1 to 4 in this case?

Comment: Or sir, I would like to happen this way. I have a draggable circle_mc, then, it will hit any objects or MovieClips on stage. Is it possible to know the instance name being hit by the circle_mc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < _totalRecObjects; ++i) {
   circle_mc.hitTestObject(this["rec" + i]);
}
```